# Is there a -fno-operator-names option for clang-format?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, clang-format

C++ has keyword aliases for the binary operators `||`, `&&`, etc. called `or`, `and`, etc.
I can disable those aliases in gcc and clang and not treat them as keywords with `-fno-operator-names`, so that I can have a function called `xor` for example.

Is there such an option for clang-format as well?

Without such an option clang-format outputs the following with the Mozilla style for example:

```cpp
int xor () { return 1; }

  int g()
{
  return 2;
}
```

However, I want it formatted like the following:

```cpp
int
xor()
{
  return 1;
}

int
g()
{
  return 2;
}
```

Edit: I know `xor` is a reseverd keyword, but I have existing code that uses `xor` as a function name using the `-fno-operator-names` compiler option and I simply want to format that code.

Comment: FWIW `xor` is a reserved name in C++ so you can't legally write an `xor` function.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword

Comment: _"I have existing code that uses `xor` as a function name"_ - the better option would probably be to rename the `xor` function into `operator^`. `xor` should then work out of the box.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: "*xor should then work out of the box.*" No, it wouldn't. If `xor` is being used as a function name, having it interpreted as `^` would break stuff. You'd have to put `operator` in front of it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Very true and looking at the current signature of the `xor` function I doubt even that will help.